# Compute $\sum_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(k + 1) ^ 2}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Compute
$$\sum_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(k + 1) ^ 2}{k!}.$$

---

Today I have participated in [Olympiad](https://yandexdataschool.ru/) which had 8 different tasks. This was one of them.

I've started by substituting concrete values and looking for a pattern:
$\sum_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(k + 1) ^ 2}{k!} = 1 - \frac{2^2}{1!} + \frac{3^2}{2!} - \frac{4^2}{3!} + \frac{5^2}{4!} + \dots$

This gave me insight that it may be connected to the following series:
$e = 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \dots$

After that for a few hours I was trying to transform original series to the series for $e$. My intuition tells me that the result is something similar to $e \times constant$. But I wasn't able to prove it or disprove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the operator $ \frac{d}{dx}x $ twice to
$$ e^{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}, $$
and then set $x=-1$. Notice that
$$ \left(\frac{d}{dx}x\right)^2 x^k = (k+1)^2x^k. $$

Comment: Could you, please, explain how to read the left part: $\left(\frac{d}{dx}x\right)^2 x^k$. I don't understand this notation.

Comment: It means $ \left( \frac{d}{dx} x \right) \left( \frac{d}{dx} x \right) x^k $ $A^n$ means applying the operator $A$ $n$ times (think matrices, for example).

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now. It is the neatest solution in my opinion :)

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

As $(k+1)^2=k(k-1)+3k+1,$

For $k\ge2,$
$$\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{k!}=\dfrac1{(k-2)!}+3\cdot\dfrac1{(k-1)!}+\dfrac1{k!}$$

$$\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{k!}x^k=x^2\cdot\dfrac{x^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}+3x\cdot\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$

For $k=0,$  $$\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{k!}x^k=1$$

For $k=1,$  $$\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{k!}x^k=4x=3x\cdot\dfrac1{0!}=\dfrac{x^1}{1!}$$

Now use $\displaystyle e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$

Answer (score 1):

$(k+1)^2 = 2\binom{k}{2}+3k+1$, and
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\binom{k}{n} = [x^n]\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k (x+1)^k}{k!} = [x^n] e^{-(x+1)} = \frac{(-1)^n}{e n!} \tag{1}$$
hence it follows that:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(k+1)^2 = 2\frac{(-1)^2}{2!e}+3\frac{(-1)^1}{1!e}+\frac{(-1)^0}{0!e}=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{e}}.\tag{2}$$